# An exceptionHandling error4

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
display += Convert.ToString(GridView1.SelectedValue);
```

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information:

> Data keys must be specified on GridView 'GridView1' before the selected data keys can be retrieved.  Use the DataKeyNames property to specify data keys.

Code snippet for GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged that contains the culprit:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    string display = "Combo="; 
    int s; 
    total_cost = 0; 
    s = GridView1.SelectedIndex; 
    switch (s) 
    { 
        case 0: 
            bool isInt = int.TryParse(lbl_total_price.Text, out total_cost ); 
            display += Convert.ToString(GridView1.SelectedValue); 
            lbl_combo_cost.Text = "100"; 
            total_cost += 100; 
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please share a code sample. What is "display"?

Comment: protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string display = "Combo=";
            int s;
            total_cost = 0;
        s = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
        switch (s)
        {
            case 0:
                
bool isInt = int.TryParse(lbl_total_price.Text,  out total_cost );
                display += Convert.ToString(GridView1.SelectedValue);
                lbl_combo_cost.Text = "100";
                total_cost += 100;
                break;

Comment: please edit and update your post.

Comment: the above shown is a part of my code, when i run i get the error but i dont understand what s wrong in this.

Comment: post the code of your GridView1 please.

Comment: protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string display = "Combo=";
            int s;
            total_cost = 0;
        s = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
        switch (s)
        {
            case 0:
                
bool isInt = int.TryParse(lbl_total_price.Text,  out total_cost );
                display += Convert.ToString(GridView1.SelectedValue);
                lbl_combo_cost.Text = "100";
                total_cost += 100;
                break;

Comment: no, that is the code of your GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged method (and only partial at that).

Comment: i ll split the codes and send

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcemenu" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="527px">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="combo_name" SortExpression="combo_name">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("combo_name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>

Comment: <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("combo_name") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="combo_items" SortExpression="combo_items">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("combo_items") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>

Comment: <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("combo_items") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="combo_price" SortExpression="combo_price">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("combo_price") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>

Comment: <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("combo_price") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

Answer (score 0):

The exception you are getting explains what you need to do.

> Data keys must be specified on GridView 'GridView1' before the selected data keys can be retrieved. Use the DataKeyNames property to specify data keys.

In your GridView, you have to define which field (property) should act as key. This is usually the identifier (e.g. ID) property in your data. You can use the `DataKeyNames` property on the `GridView` for this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcemenu" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="527px" 
    DataKeyNames="MyId">
```

Here, the `MyId` should be replaced with the name of the your property that should act as key.

Comment: Thank you soo much...that error has gone...some more work to do on that ....hope you will help me furthur...Thanks a lot